# How to use Request::old() for dynamic inputs in laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel-5, request

I'm confuse how can I use `Request::old()` in laravel if I have dynamic `<inputs>` **WITHOUT** changing the name of the `<inputs>`. Here's my code below:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}"><br>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}"><br>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}"><br>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

try write code in laravel using {{ old('name') }}

> `<input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{ old('name') }}"><br>`

Comment: Its now working. I think it is the same as `Request::old('name')`